# Most Powerful Test Neymann Pearson Lemma

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

If anyone can help with this problem I would greatly appreciate it.

[image]

I don't really understand the neyman pearson lemma and I have no idea how to calculate this. Any steps and/or explaination would be great.

Comment: You could start by calculating and ordering the likelihood ratios.

Comment: But would that be for each combination of likelihood ratios? or is it just the product each of the rows?

Comment: For example the likelihood ratio for $x=5$ is $\dfrac{f(5,H_0)}{f(5,H_1)} = \dfrac12$